# Visual Studio 2013 Theme change on 1 computer only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, colors

We have a group of developers that share the same visual studio on a dev account. I want to be able to change the theme on my computer only.

When changing the theme (Tools->Options->Environment,General), everyone tied to that account has their theme changed as well. They prefer white, but I can't stare at that on 3 screens for 8 hours. Kills my eyes. I have to have the dark theme.

After googling this for the last hour, I haven't found anything specific to this question. Is it a bug? Or a Windows 10 thing?

Comment: do you use the same VS installation simultaneously with different accounts??

Comment: We are using the same installation, but it is all on the same account, so changes made to my VS environment effect the other devs. I posted the answer below. You just have to un-sync your local machine VS.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. My Google Foo was weak this morning.

In Tools -> Options -> Environment. If you look down in the sublist under Environment, you will see Synchronized Settings. Go there, then simply turn off the Appearance checkbox and you are good to go... no more screaming co-workers :)